# Getting part of the text inside div with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have got this HTML code and I'm trying to get values of SizeX, SizeY and Color.

```
<div id="index">
  <h2>Things</h2>
  <p><span>SizeX: </span><strong>15</strong></p>
  <p><span>SizeY: </span><strong>25</strong></p>
  <p><span>Color: </span><strong>red</strong></p>
</div>
```

http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/f82d98de7f4d3d8475f359c0fefbed2c1439723962777/index.html

This what I did so far (doing it all in Developer's Console). First I stored `#index` inside variable, with this command `var parameters = $("#index");`.

Now after I have got everything stored in variable, I try to get first value (SizeX) with this command:

```
var SizeX = /<span>sizex: <\/span><strong>(\w+)/i.exec(parameters);
```

Then I call `SizeX` to see result and the result is `null`. I have no idea why, my regex should be right, considering it works there https://regex101.com/r/hV1mB5/1.

And I'm using exec the same way it's shown here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp.

Thanks. :)

Comment: If you downvote me, tell me what's wrong with my question and I will fix it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be in for a headache if you use regex with HTML. That's just bad, hands down.

A better way would be to use jQuery's `$.fn.text` method.

```
var elem = $('#index');
var obj = {};
elem.find('span').each(function(){
   obj[$(this).text().replace(/\W/g, "")] = $(this).next().text().trim();
});
```

You know, you are just using bracket-notation and making the span's text without non-alphabetical characters(which are removed), the property name and we are assigning the trimmed text of the *next* element, which is `<strong>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex at all:

```
$( "#index strong").each(function( index ) {
  console.log(  $( this ).text() );
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/vr7rxb3p/**

Update:

```
console.log(  $(this).prev().text()+':'+$( this ).text() );
```

now make vars, put them in array/object, or whatever you want...